# Find the year value from a given date pattern

Tags: java

I have to write a function that takes input of a date and a date format and  returns the year . Some of the valid scenarios are :

```
1) dateformat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
   date ="2018-10-26"
   output : 2018
2) dateformat = "dd-mm-yy"
   date ="28-10-16"
   output : 16
3) dateformat = "yyQQ"
   date ="16Q2"
   output : 16
```

So , the format can vary depending on the dataset .
The formats can also be  like yyyy/mm/dd, yyww(weekly data like 18w1 -> meaning 1st week of 2018 etc.

The logic I have been thinking of is to search of the position of consecutive 'y's in the pattern and once I can use that information to parse the date.How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Try to parse three format one by one until you got the result without exception.

Comment: The formats are not finite. it can be something like yyyy/mm/dd, yyww(weekly data like 18w1 -> meaning 1st week of 2018)

Comment: *FYI:* Format `"yyyy-mm-dd"` is wrong, it should be `"yyyy-MM-dd"`

Comment: do you know the date format at runtime? or do you just get a date and have to guess the underlying format?

Answer (score 1):

Just ask [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to parse the string for you, then get the `year` value:

```java
static int getYear(String dateformat, String date) {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateformat).parse(date).get(ChronoField.YEAR);
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(getYear("yyyy-MM-dd", "2018-10-26"));
System.out.println(getYear("dd-MM-yy", "28-10-16"));
System.out.println(getYear("yy'Q'Q", "16Q2"));
```

*Output*

```
2018
2016
2016
```

Comment: OP says `The formats are not finite`(2nd comment) May be need some magic for this

Comment: @Eklavya Which is why *the format has to be specified*, otherwise it is impossible to determine the year of input `"01-02-03"`. Is it 2001 or 2003? --- The logic above is general code for getting the year value, given a `dateformat` *and* a  `date`, just like specified in the question.

Comment: Actually proper answer would be what are you saying now.

Comment: @Eklavya I though I already said it by making a method that requires the `dateformat` and the `date` value to *both* be given. --- Also, read first sentence of question: *"write a function that takes input of a date and a date format and returns the year"* --- That is *exactly* what my answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

create a list of regular expressions and put them into dict.
something like
date_format_dict = {}
date_format_dict["yyyy/mm/dd"]="[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}

When you get a date, use the regular expressions to match it, when the correct regular expression is found, you can know the format string, you then know which part is the year part.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Pattern matcher in java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```
public static String getYear(String fmt  , String data) {
        String yearPattern="[Y]+";
        String year=null;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(yearPattern,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);    
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fmt);       
        while (matcher.find()) {    
            year=data.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end())  ; 
        }   
        return year;
    }
```

Comment: Patterns are not always one-for-one with input. E.g. `"MMMM d, y"` parses `"November 13, 2020"` correctly as `2020-11-13`, but the year value is not at start/end index 8-9 as indicated by the pattern, but at start/end index 13-17.